# Adding Registry Keys on Remote Windows Server Machine not working

Tags: msbuild, registry, windows-server-2008-r2, msbuild-task

I have two domain joined machines (ServerA & ServerB) running Windows Server 2012 R2.

I want to add new registry key in ServerB from ServerA.
I am running below command in ServerA:

```
reg add \\ServerB\HKLM\SOFTWARE\MyCompany\MyApp /v Username /t REG_SZ /d ABC123 /f
```

Output from above command: **The operation completed successfully.**

**But when I checked registry in ServerB, I didn't find the newly added key.**

I am using MSBuild to run this command inside a script in ServerA.

> Deploy.proj

```
  <Target Name="Deploy_Registry">

<!--Make sure the Remote Registry service is started-->
<ServiceController MachineName="ServerB" ServiceName="Remote Registry" Action="Start" ContinueOnError="true"/>
<Exec Command='reg add \\ServerB\HKLM\SOFTWARE\MyCompany\MyApp /v Username /t REG_SZ /d ABC123 /f' ContinueOnError='false' /></Target>
```

Comment: Have you tried to run the command outside `msbuild`?

Comment: Why `ContinueOnError="true"`? Maybe there is an error and there are no connection to `ServerB`?

Comment: @Baruch yes I tried running it outside MSBuild and it worked.

Comment: But it does not work when using MSBuild